# R-markdown formatting output of computations

Tags: format, r-markdown

In R markdown the following block will generate:

````
```{r some computations, echo = F}
cat(4+6)

```
````

Output:

```
## 10
```

How can get rid of the `##` part and simply output the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in the options for the code chunks:

````
```{r some computations, echo = F, comment = ''}
{cat(4+6)}

```
````

This will do the trick.
Or if you don't want to set it again and again do it once for the document.
Like this:

````
```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  comment = ''
)
```

```{r some computations, echo = F}
{cat(4+6)}

```
````

Here is the homepage from Yihui Xie (rmarkdown creator) with a nice list of all possible chunk options: https://yihui.org/knitr/options